# Use RxJava in order to parse an item and create a new one from the previous

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have the following Object and i want to use RxJava in order to create a new object. The logic behind this is that each article has a lot of comments. And it finds the correct comments using the ArticleData.commentId and the Comment.id.

```
public class ArticlesResponse  {
    public List<ArticleData> articles;
    public List<Data> comments;
}

public class Data {
    public int id;
    public String link;
    public String title;
    public String author
    public String body;
}

public class ArticleData extends Data {
        public List<int> commentId;
}
```

So how can i use Rxjava in order to create the following object

```
public class Article extends Data {
        public List<Comments> comments;
}

public class Comments extends Data {
      // comments will have more attributes in the feature
      // so use a seperate object
}
```

I know that i have to use the flapMap and the filter in order to parse the "ArticleResponse" but i don't know how to put all this together.
Furthermore the "ArticleResponse" is being generated from a json which i got from Retrofit, so i guess it will be better to use RxJava since i already have the Observable instead of putting nested for's inside my Callback.

Comment: Maybe your code snippet has some error?

Comment: What does it means `public class Data extends {` ?

Comment: Yes that is a typo... It doesn't exist on the real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you means that articlesResponse.comments is a list contains all Comments of these all ArticleData, although I don't think wrap these data together and do the map operation in client is a good idea, this job should be done at server.

And I think maybe your `ArticlesResponse`'s `comments` field should be a `List<Comments>`.

With these assumption, the code below may do the job you want (I put them in a `TempTest` class, and define an interface you described, and mock it to pass javac compile, and I also use Java 8 lambda grammar for code simplicity).

```
public class TempTest {

  public static class Data {
    public int id;
    public String link;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String body;
  }

  public static class ArticleData extends Data {
    public List<Integer> commentId;
  }

  public static class Comments extends Data {
    // comments will have more attributes in the feature
    // so use a seperate object
  }

  public static class ArticlesResponse {
    public List<ArticleData> articles;
    public List<Comments> comments;
  }

  public class Article extends Data {
    public List<Comments> comments;
  }

  public interface TestInterface {
    Observable<ArticlesResponse> getArticle();
  }

  public static Comments findCommentWithId(int commentId, List<Comments> comments) {
    for (Comments comment : comments) {
        if (comment.id == commentId) {
            return comment;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Test
  public void simpleTestcase() {
    // assume you means that articlesResponse.comments is a list contains all Comments of these
    // all ArticleData, although I don't think wrap these data together and do the map operation
    // in client is a good idea, this job should be done at server
    TestInterface testInterface = mock(TestInterface.class);
    testInterface.getArticle().map(articlesResponse -> {
        List<Article> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // for each ArticleData in articlesResponse.articles
        for (ArticleData articleData : articlesResponse.articles) {
            // get all Comments from articlesResponse.comments
            Article article = new Article();
            // ... copy Data field from articleData to article
            article.comments = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Integer id : articleData.commentId) {
                Comments comment = findCommentWithId(id, articlesResponse.comments);
                if (comment != null) {
                    article.comments.add(comment);
                }
            }
            result.add(article);
        }
        return result;
    }).subscribe(articles -> {
        for (Article article : articles) {
            System.out.println(article);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. That was exactly what i was looking for.
I know that the mapping should be done in the server, but this is how we get our json and we cannot change it.

Comment: @kokeroulis ,If you think my answer is useful, please accept it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of confused at what your actual question is, so hopefully this helps.  Retrofit can return an Observable for you, which should make RxJava integration easy.  For example, in your service you could make:

```
@GET(<your endpoint>)
Observable<ArticlesResponse> getArticles();
```

And call it like:

```
<yourService>.getArticles()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedules.mainThread())
    .subscribe() // manipulate how you want
```

Comment: Ok let me make it a bit more clear.
I have the Observable<ArticlesResponse>, how can i create two new observables from this one? (The new objecsts are going to be populated from the data of the ArticlesResponse) The first one it will be class X and the  second it will be class Y. When both of them gets created, i want to merge the X and Y observable in order to create the Z observable. Sorry for the above comment, i miss clicked on the add comment...